# Is it possible to perform an CSRF attack on WCF service with webHttpBinding?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, security

We are using WCF service with `webHttpBinding` binding to expose endpoint to clients. Service is hosted by IIS (.svc). Client is JavaScript generated automatically using `enableWebScript` behavior. All methods are using POST.

Is it possible to make an CSRF attack to this service?

I considered the following options:

- AJAX - not possible, because cross site requests are not allowed (I am assuming that our site isn't prone to XSS)
- HTML Form submit - not possible, because service requires certain HTTP headers which can't be set using HTML form

Is there any other option? Flash, Silverlight, web sockets or something else?

Valid request looks like this:

```
POST http://site/Service.svc/ServiceMethod HTTP/1.1
Host: site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: cs,en-us;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,pl;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://site/
Content-Length: 33
Cookie: cookies, session id, etc.
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"param1":11,"param2":"123"}
```

To be clear: I am trying to secure my service. Not perform an attack. I am considering adding an "authentication token" to every call, but first I would like to know if it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but it's the first thing that shows up on Google for "WCF CSRC StackOverflow.com", so here's OWASP's opinion on the referral header:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_The_Referer_Header

The other answer here is somewhat misleading. The referrer header is a useful method for checking for CSRF, but is not entirely reliable. A more reliable method is to use a random token embedded in each of your forms (preferrably randomly generated for each instance of the form) that will be checked server-side.

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type='text' name='securityfield' /><input type='submit' value='submit' />
    <input type='hidden' value='<some random token>' name='CSRF-token' />
    </form
</body>
</html>
```

In MVC code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SomeAction(Dictionary<string, string> parameters){
    if(parameters["CSRF-token"] != UserContext.csrfToken){
        return View();
    }

    //Do actual work
}
```

The reason this is necessary is because a CSRF attack uses the victim's browser which may still be logged into your site. This can happen if a user has multiple tabs open, or if your sessions simply take a while to expire. An attacker will typically redirect the user to your form submission page with malicious data.

I should also say that AJAX is not cross-domain. Furthermore, XSS does not require AJAX to be implemented.

Comment: The article you linked explicitly says "Although it is trivial to spoof the referer header on your own browser, it is impossible to do so in a CSRF attack"

Comment: Edited for wrongness about the referral header. I posted the OWASP link without removing my referral-header hate.

Comment: AJAX is allowed cross domain since [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) made this possible. Note that lack of CORS headers does not mitigate against CSRF beacuse [requests can still me made cross-domain, if not read](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/58811/8340)

Answer (score -1):

In general, checking the Referrer header is sufficient to prevent CSRF, because the browser will set the referrer header (even if it was set by javascript).

I don't think anyone will be able to guarantee that your service is safe from CSRF, because it is always possible that you could (accidentally) open up some attack vector. For instance, if you have the following sites:

```
http://mycompanysite.com/MyService/Service.svc (hosting the service)
http://mycompanysite.com/MyWebApp/ (hosting a web app)
```

Then a vulnerability in the web application may allow for an attack because the "cross domain" rules no longer apply. Additionally, there is always a possibility that there is a vulnerability in the client application (i.e. the browser), so from a hosting perspective, you can really only work from the basis that users are using a well known, up-to-date browser without plugins, etc.

Comment: The problem with Referrer checking is that there is still a significant number of users who have disabled setting the Referrer header. And I don't want to cut them out. What do you think about this?

Comment: Another problem with referrer checking is that it can be forged. Using the referrer header is virtually useless. The only meaningful way of protecting against CSRF is by using random tokens stored server-side and in a given form.

Comment: @TheMonarch You are correct that it can be forged, but the purpose of CSRF controls is to protect the end-user not the service, so forging a referrer header is pointless unless you want to allow yourself to fall victim to CSRF.